How can I start WPF if Windows, and Console if Linux
Following scenario: I need an application that runs on Linux and Windows. The plan is: the user opens the application, then the application scans the OS. If it is Windows, a WPF application starts, if it is Linux a normal commandline application starts. all of these application projects are in the same solution. Is this even possible? I always get errors like
"
Error NU1201 Project Client.Windows is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Project Client.Windows supports: net8.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0) Client.EntryPoint
"
This is my current EntryPoint.Program.cs and my .csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0;net8.0-windows7.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>



    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Client.Windows\Client.Windows.csproj"></ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WINDOWS");
            // here the code to start the wpf application in Client.Windows

        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LINUX");
            // here the code to start the command application in Client.Linux
        } 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OS NOT SUPPORTED");
        }
    }
}


You'll need two projects for the best experience. One normal desktop program for the WPF part and a second console application for running on Linux. Since both executables are fundamentally different (target different subsystems) you'll ru into problems when ran in the "wrong" environment.

Use Avalonia UI instead of WPF. It runs on Windows, Linux and many other platforms and is a WPF clone.

@Alejandro jeah that's what i currently have, but how can i start them based on the os? i rly want one solution for both, bcs wpf and the console application are only a small part of a bigger project, and 95% of the code can be shared between the linux and the windows application (services, util functions, controller, etc)

@OlivierJacot-Descombes for avalonia you need a license to use in a company, and all linux clients are command only so i dont need a gui there

The user would launch one or the other based on the platform, knowing that the wrong one won't work. You can move the common code to a class library dll file that both uses, so no code repetition at all, each platform-specific project would only have code for the platform-specific UI and call the shared code.

I see. So, you will need 3 projects: A Class Library project where you have all the common types and implement all the common business logic, a WPF project and a Console App project with only UI stuff who both reference this library.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes okay so I basically just keep my solution as it was, and just remove the EntryPoint where the OS check happened, add references for my business logic to both projects and then i release the windows projekt and linux project seperately. sad, i rly hopped i could just do one release for both, i thought the wpf on linux doesnt matter bcs i won't open

You can merge all the EXEs and DLLs into one folder and always release them in a single distribution, but the WPF application will not run on LINUX.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes jeah I know thats why i use console for linux, my original problem was that i couldnt do a "if windows then Clien.Wpf.Start else if linux then Client.Cli.Start" bcs i got reference errors in visual studio
